# JQuery add button in a form

Tags: html, jquery, forms, addition

I'm not very good at JQuery. I only need to add a "add" and "remove" line to a form, to create an array of rooms in an hotel.
Trying to adapt a code found on the Internet, I arrived to the following code:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
              $("#add").click(function() {
                  div = document.createElement('div');
                  $(div).addClass("room").html("new Room Type");
                  $("#roomTypes").append(div);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #container {border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; width: 100%;}
            .inner {border: 1px solid green; margin: 10px; width: auto; height: 20px;}
           </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>Numbers Project</h1>
        <p>Version 0.1</p>
        
        <form>
            Hotel Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="Roma Nord"><br>
            Hotel Stars: <input type="number" name="Stars" value="3"><br>
            
            <div id="roomTypes">
                <div class="room">
                    Room Type: <input type="text" name="RoomType" value="Double"><br>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <button id="add">Add new div</button>
            Opening Date: <input type="date" name="OpenDate" value="2021-01-01"><br>
            Closing Date: <input type="date" name="CloseDate" value="2021-06-30"><br>
            <h3>Previous Year Data</h3>

            Rooms sold: <input type="number" name="RoomsSold" value="12000"><br>
            Arrivals Presences: <input type="number" name="ArrivalsPresences" value="15000"><br>
            Presences: <input type="number" name="Presences" value="23000"><br>
            
            <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

But the button shows the new Div only for a second, then it disappears.
The line:

```
<button id="add">Add new div</button>
```

works only if I put it out of the form (in the Body).
Can anybody help me to add these buttons?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: `<button id=` -> `<button type='button' id=` - your button is submitting the form, so change it to button-only, the default is to submit.   Alternatively add `return false;` to the end of your button click handler.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `form` submit and reload the page just add

```
<button id="add" type="button">Add new div</button>
```

Your full code working:

```js
 $(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        $(div).addClass("room").html("new Room Type");
        $("#roomTypes").append(div);
      });
  });
```

```css
 #container {border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; width: 100%;}
            .inner {border: 1px solid green; margin: 10px; width: auto; height: 20px;}
```

```html
<html>
    <header>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>Numbers Project</h1>
        <p>Version 0.1</p>
        
        <form>
            Hotel Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="Roma Nord"><br>
            Hotel Stars: <input type="number" name="Stars" value="3"><br>
            
            <div id="roomTypes">
                <div class="room">
                    Room Type: <input type="text" name="RoomType" value="Double"><br>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <button id="add" type='button'>Add new div</button>
            Opening Date: <input type="date" name="OpenDate" value="2021-01-01"><br>
            Closing Date: <input type="date" name="CloseDate" value="2021-06-30"><br>
            <h3>Previous Year Data</h3>

            Rooms sold: <input type="number" name="RoomsSold" value="12000"><br>
            Arrivals Presences: <input type="number" name="ArrivalsPresences" value="15000"><br>
            Presences: <input type="number" name="Presences" value="23000"><br>
            
            <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```